# Breeze.js and WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack, breeze

Has anyone out there used breeze.js with webpack?

I cannot seem to get it to work together.  If anyone has made this work, can you please share your webpack.config.js (and any other relevant configurations)?

I just get the error `breeze is not defined` or an error about Q not being setup.

If you use typescript I would love to see how you set that up too, but I would be happy with just a javascript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Q

To get Q working, you should probably use the ProvidePlugin. Breeze expects Q to be uppercase, but in npm land it's lowercase. Assuming you've run `npm install --save q`, then you should be able to add:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Q: "q"
})
```

to your webpack.config.js and that will keep breeze happy.

## breeze

This might also resolve this issue with `breeze is not defined`: that could be because Q is not loaded. Otherwise, make sure you've installed breeze via npm or bower, and then wherever you need breeze, you need to `var breeze = require('breeze-client/breeze.debug');`

Alternatively, you can include `require("expose?breeze!breeze-client/breeze.debug");` just once in your entry file and that will add breeze to global scope.

Comment: Is was absolutely brilliant!  Thank you so very much!

Comment: Is it possible to do the `require("expose?breeze!breeze-client/breeze.debug");` in the `webpack.config` file?  I tried a loader like this: `{ test: require.resolve('breeze'), loader: 'expose?breeze!breeze-client/breeze.debug'}` and it tells me that it `Cannot find module 'breeze'`.

Comment: I think you could do `{ test: require.resolve('breeze-client/breeze.debug'), loader: 'expose?breeze'}` - but I think this still depends on you require'ing breeze in your files as `require('breeze-client/breeze.debug')`. You could combine this with `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ breeze: "breeze-client/breeze.debug" })` and then simply `require("breeze")` in your files